# Removed `$DB::single = 1` surviving Perl debugger's `R`?

Tags: perl, debugging, breakpoints, restart

While debugging my package code I was lazy and added `$DB::single = 1;` where I wanted to have a breakpoint until the code works correctly (it took quite some time to rewrite the code to make it correct).

Well finally the code was OK, and I removed the `$DB::single = 1;` line, saved the buffer (Emacs speak), and pressed `R` in a different terminal to reload the program.

Surprisingly the program still stopped where `$DB::single = 1;` had been in the past, but now is not present not anymore.

So I wonder: Is it because the Perl debugger did not reload the package code (as I did not increment `$VERSION`, or is it a bug in the debugger that keeps the information about `$DB::single = 1;` (just as breakpoints are remembered across `R` (as line number))?

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why the effect is there, but I found out that I can delete those breakpoints like normal breakpoints using "**B** *line_number*" at the debugger prompt.